# UPDATE source table, AFTER Grouping?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (source) with payments for a person - called 'Item' in the example below.

This table will have payments for each person, added to it over a period.

I then generate invoices, which basically takes all the payments for a particular person, and sums them up into a single row.

This must be stored in an invoice table, for auditing reasons.

I do this in the example below.

What I am missing, though, as I am not sure how to do it, is that each payment, once assigned to the Invoice table, needs to had the Invoice ID that it was assigned to, stored in the Items table.

So, see the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,
    PaymentValue DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
    AssignedToInvoiceID INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Invoice 
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  PersonID INT NOT NULL,
  Value DECIMAL(16,2)

)

INSERT INTO Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (1, 100)
INSERT INTO Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (2, 132)
INSERT INTO Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (2, 65)
INSERT INTO Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (1, 25)
INSERT INTO Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (3, 69)

SELECT * FROM Items

INSERT INTO Invoice (PersonID, Value)
SELECT PersonID, SUM(PaymentValue) FROM Items
WHERE  AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL
GROUP BY PersonID

SELECT * FROM Invoice

DROP TABLE Items
DROP TABLE Invoice
```

What I need to do is then update the Items table, to say that the first row has been assigned to Invoice.ID 1, row two was assigned to Invoice ID 2. Row 3, was assigned to Invoice ID 2 as well.

Note, there are many other columns in the table. This is a basic example.

Simply, I need to record which invoice, each source row was assigned to.

Comment: How will your system know which invoice the payment was applied to... e.g. do you just select the earliest invoice with an amount outstanding? if that is the case a payment could be applied to 1 or more invoices?

Comment: I'm not sure how to know. That's the issue I am facing. (OUTPUT clause, somehow, maybe?). A line can only be assigned to one invoice, though.

Comment: `I then generate invoices, which basically takes all the payments for a particular person, and sums them up into a single row.` so there is one `invoice` per person?

Comment: Should the ID column in Invoice table be used to update the AssignedToInvoiceID column in Items table?

Comment: @shree.pat18 - Yes, the Invoice.ID should then be written to the 'AssignedToInvoiceID'.

Comment: @GB - No, there can be multiple invoices per person. Each time to code is run (That does the grouping), a new Invoice will be created, grouping the rows that don't have an 'AssignedToInvoiceID' set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here to ensure payments are correctly linked to invoices is to ensure that:

A: No updates are made to Items between reading the unassigned items and updating AssignedToInvoiceID.

B: No new invoices are created with the Items being process before updating AssignedToInvoiceID.

As you are updating two tables it will have to be a two step process. To ensure A it will need to be run in a transaction with a least REPEATABLE READ isolation. To ensure B requires a transaction with SERIALIZABLE isolation. See [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

It can be done like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

DECLARE @newInvoices TABLE (PersonID INT, InvoiceID INT)

INSERT INTO Invoice (PersonID, Value)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.PersonID INTO @newInvoices(InvoiceID, PersonID)
SELECT PersonID, SUM(PaymentValue) FROM Items
WHERE AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL
GROUP BY PersonID

UPDATE Items
    SET AssignedToInvoiceID = InvoiceID
FROM Items
INNER JOIN @newInvoices newInvoice ON newInvoice.PersonID = Items.PersonID
WHERE AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL

COMMIT
```

An alternative if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later is to use the [SEQUNCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) object, this will allow the Items to be assigned new invoice IDs before the Invoices are created, reducing the locking required.

It works like this:

```
-- Run once with your table setup.
CREATE SEQUENCE InvoiceIDs AS INT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1

CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,
    PaymentValue DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
    AssignedToInvoiceID INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Invoice 
(
  -- No longer a IDENTITY column
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  PersonID INT NOT NULL,
  Value DECIMAL(16,2)

)

BEGIN TRAN 

DECLARE @newInvoiceLines TABLE (PersonID INT, InvoiceID INT, PaymentValue DECIMAL(16,2))

-- Reading and updating AssignedToInvoiceID happens in one query so is thread safe.
UPDATE Items
    SET AssignedToInvoiceID = newInvoices.InvoiceID
OUTPUT inserted.PersonID, inserted.AssignedToInvoiceID, inserted.PaymentValue 
    INTO @newInvoiceLines(PersonID, InvoiceID, PaymentValue)
FROM Items
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PersonID, NEXT VALUE FOR InvoiceIDs AS InvoiceID
    FROM Items
    GROUP BY PersonID
) AS newInvoices ON newInvoices.PersonID = Items.PersonID
WHERE Items.AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL

INSERT INTO Invoice (ID, PersonID, Value)
SELECT InvoiceID, PersonID, SUM(PaymentValue) FROM @newInvoiceLines
GROUP BY PersonID, InvoiceID

COMMIT
```

You will still want to use a transaction to ensure the Invoice gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you could run an update from join after you have inserted records into Invoices table, like so:

```
update items
set assignedtoinvoiceid = v.id
from
items m
inner join invoice v on m.personid = v.personid
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PZWKNA8527)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do an invoice "run", select the most recent invoice for each person something like,

```
update items
set AssignedToInvoiceID = inv.id
from 
    (select personid, max(id) id
    from invoice
    group by personid) inv
where items.personid = inv.personid
    and AssignedToInvoiceID is null
```

this assumes that AssignedToInvoiceID is null when it isn't populated, if it gets defaulted to an empty string or something then you would need to change the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get `MAX(ID)` from `Invoice` table before inserting new rows from `Items` table. Store this value into a variable: `@MaxInvoiceID`

2) After inserting records into `Invoice` table, update `AssignedToInvoiceID` in `Items` table with `Invoice.ID>@MaxInvoiceID`

Refer below code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Items
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,
    PaymentValue DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
    AssignedToInvoiceID INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #Invoice 
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  PersonID INT NOT NULL,
  Value DECIMAL(16,2)

)

DECLARE @MaxInvoiceID INT;
SELECT @MaxInvoiceID=ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM #Invoice
SELECT @MaxInvoiceID

INSERT INTO #Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (1, 100)
INSERT INTO #Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (2, 132)
INSERT INTO #Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (2, 65)
INSERT INTO #Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (1, 25)
INSERT INTO #Items (PersonID, PaymentValue) VALUES (3, 69)

SELECT * FROM #Items

INSERT INTO #Invoice (PersonID, Value)
SELECT PersonID, SUM(PaymentValue) 
FROM #Items
WHERE  AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL
GROUP BY PersonID

SELECT * FROM #Invoice

UPDATE Itm
SET Itm.AssignedToInvoiceID=Inv.ID
FROM #Items Itm
JOIN #Invoice Inv ON Itm.PersonID=Inv.PersonID AND Itm.AssignedToInvoiceID IS NULL AND Inv.ID>@MaxInvoiceID

SELECT * FROM #Items

DROP TABLE #Items
DROP TABLE #Invoice
```